# Are there Peirushim on the Tisha BAv Night kinot available on the internet?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, song-poetry, tisha-bav, commentaries

In my preperation for this evening I have found lots of material for tomorrow's kinot, however, I have found next to nothing on this evening's kinot (Zekhor Hashem, Baleil Zeh, Shomron Kol Titein and Ad Ana Bikhyah B'Tziyon).

Does anyone know of any resources available online that I could look at?

Comment: Note that Shomron Kol Titein is often repeated during the day and you may find commentaries on it there.

Comment: oooh good call on the Shomron Kol Titein, I'll look it up.

Comment: Just wondered whether you found any commentaries on Shomron Kol Titein Kinnah 4, 46. I haven't found anything. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi [Aharon Wechselstein](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2363402&forum_id=19616), author of the acclaimed [Sefer Avoteinu](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?199823&) and [Sefer Rabboteinu](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?199831&), also wrote a complete commentary on the Kinnos, including those for the evening. The entire commentary is freely available [online](https://sites.google.com/site/rebbarn1/kinnot01).

[Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51217&st=&pgnum=61) is a Sefer Kinnos, published by *Hotzaat Ohr HaBahir* in 1965 with dual commentaries, Beit Levi and Mateh Levi, explaining the words and content of all the Kinnos.

Rabbi Tzvi Haber of TorahLabs has some short thoughts on the evening Kinnos [here](http://www.torahlab.org/download/Tisha%20B'Av%202014%20v.1.pdf), as part of a larger compilation of insights into the Kinnos from his father, Rabbi [Yaakov Haber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaacov_Haber).

I also found [this](https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=21441) brief explanatory commentary by one Avraham Oman, which clarifies poetic and vague terms throughout the Kinnos.

Comment: the 4th link is broken.